# AmqpAdmin.deleteQueue() reasserts?

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, amqp

I'm using AmqpAdmin.deleteQueue(queueName) in my application. Oddly, however, when this code runs,it causes the queues (which were earlier unbound from their exchanges) to not only not be deleted, but also re-bound to their old exchanges.

Thanks!

I've commented the code to delete the queue and it is definitely the culprit in causing the queues to get rebound.